# Google OAuth with Firebase Authentication without collecting emails

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I've implemented Firebase Authentication into my iOS app for user sign-in. I've enabled Sign In With Apple and Google OAuth.

With Apple sign-in I didn't ask to collect email addresses, so in the Firebase Console these users just show up with a User UID. But Google OAuth users show up with a UID and an email address.

Is there a way to disable email collection for these Google OAuth users? I don't want to collect email addresses - I don't need them and I dislike collecting more than I need to.

Answer (score 0):

yes and no.
Hehe Firebase Auth requires an email to create user method, but given that this process doesn’t validate that the email actually exists you can just add something like:

```
var username= username + “@anything.com”
```

Also there is an example to do this here:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/username-password-auth

Comment: Doesn't help I'm afraid - I'm not personally collecting the email address, that's all being handled by the GoogleSignIn iOS framework. I just wondered if there was a way to stop those email addresses being stored in Firebase.

Comment: So, no, if you are using SSO, there is no way that you can do that. Came with the implementation of SSO.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway. Guess I shouldn't be surprised that Google would hand out more info about users that it needs to!